# import error keras.models Dense, LSTM, Embedding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cpu

I have trouble running the code from this [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-word-level-neural-language-model-in-keras/) neural language model tutorial.
It seems that I cannot import the relevant packages from keras.models although I have installed keras and tensorflow.

a) [keras installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE7GW.jpg)

b) [TensorFlow installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3JGa.jpg)

c) [Spyder error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuIfp.jpg)

I also tried to run the import command in the Windows console. There the error message says something about "the CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use".

d) [Error message in windows console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYiat.jpg)

Background info:
I am using Spyer 3.2.3 and have installed python 3.6.0.

Could you please help me to find out what the issue is?

Thank you, very much appreciated!

Comment: Rather than linking to the course, can you provide a more clear example of where you are having problems running? This question seems slightly too broad at the moment and to really help out: you might want to narrow down the error messages to provide some more clues to where you think things are going wrong.

Comment: The correct statements for importing these modules can be easily found in the 'Complete Example' section of the tutorial you link to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dense` is not a model. Dense is a layer, and it's in `keras.layers`:

```
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
```

Often I work importing everything at once and forget about it:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
import keras.backend as K #for some advanced functions
```